# How to use the requestData in the SKMutablePayment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am using the Apple IAP. I want to add some addtional paprameters like the user id, the server id, and the money of a product when requesting a payment using the `StoreKit`:

```
NSDictionary* requestDataDic = @{ @"userId": userId, @"serverId": serverId, @"money": money };

NSData* requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDataDic
                                                      options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                        error:nil];

SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:productIdentifier];
payment.requestData = requestData;

if ([SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]) {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

However, after my server side has validate the receipt, it doesn't receive the information which was sended to the Apple Server in the `requestData`. Did I misunderstand the usage of the `requestData`?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skmutablepayment/1505974-requestdata?language=objc), this property is reserved for future use and if you use it, your payment will be rejected by apple.

> The default value is nil. If requestData is not nil, your payment will be rejected by the Apple App Store.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you add a small part of the document you're referring to into your answer. The link you provide might change in the future, making this answer less useful.
And welcome to SO :)